# Symbol for the area of an Ellipse

Tags: notation

Is there any commonly used symbol for the area of an ellipse?
I'm thinking of $A(E)$ or $\mathcal{A}(E)$?

Thanks!

Comment: Is $E_1$ the symbol of your particular ellipse?

Comment: Yes! $E_1$ represent one of my ellipses.

Comment: I use $\text{Area}$.

Comment: The use of "Area" for area is the cleanest solution. However, if I need to include a lot of "Area" symbol in an article, I will use $\mu(\cdots)$ to save some space. $\mu(S)$ here  is one popular notation for the Lebesgue measure for the shape $S$.